# Android thread scheduling / management

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I currently have 2 different activities that I need to work together.

I need `Activity #1` to do some jobs first, then call `Activity#2` and wait until it has completed, then do some different jobs, then pause and call `Activity#2` again, ... etc. 

Edit: I don't know what was on my mind but I missed this piece out:
I need to update Activity 1's UI whenever I get some results from Activity 2, so I decided to put most of the code inside an AsyncTask:

```
//class Activity#1: 
    onCreate(){
     // creates UpdateUITask (the AsyncTask), pass its Context as parameter
    }
    onActivityResult()
    {
     // do something with result
    }

// the AsyncTask
class UpdateUITask implements AsyncTask{
    doInBackground(){
     // uses the passed context to call startActivityForResult(Activity#2)
     // this is done multiple times ***
    }
    publishProgress()
    { 
     // update the UI of Activity #1
    }
}
```

My problem is that what I marked with *** above is actually not paused by startActivityForResult, rather only Activity#1 is. As such the AsyncTask creates multiple instances of Activity#2 which in my case is not desirable. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Sorry for the previous inconvenience.

Comment: The term `activity` in android represents a screen. Not sure if you are using the term `activity` to represent a screen or some tread activity. Please clarify.

Comment: They are regular screen activities, although I made them run automatically and they're supposed to process some information I need for the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Start `activity#2` from `activity#1` using `startActivityForResult()`. Once the `activity#2` is done with the operations you can finish that activity. On finishing `activity#2` `onActivityResult()` described in `activity#1` will be called and you can perform the remaining operations.

Check the following link for more information:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

**EDIT**

The method `doInBackground()` runs in a non-UI thread. You are going wrong by calling `startActivityForResult(Activity#2)` from this method. If you have any process that doesn't need any user intervention, then you don't need to call any activity. Simply write that non-UI process in `doInBackground()` and `publishProgress()` in `Activity #1`

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that I missed out something important until now, I will edit the question again.